# Optimizing symfony 2 in dev environment

Tags: symfony

Websites in dev environment load in like 10 seconds, which is too much...is there any way to optimize it? I basically have default configuration, didn't change anything...What's wrong here?

The only thing I've tried is to comment out cache loading in app_dev.php, but it didn't work, loading time is still about 10 seconds.

I am running on localhost, nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use PHP 5.5+ or install some accelerator like APC.
2. Don't use controller for assetics ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)).
3. Profile your application using Xhprof or Xdebug.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5+, APC, and I don't use controller for assetics. RouteListener takes 2s, TemplateListener 2.5s, template I'm currently displaying 2s, kernel request 2s...Way too long I guess.

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.5 you can drop APC - if you need shared memory, use Redis or Memcached; Maybe HDD is causing problems - consider using SSD or some RamDisk.